# What is this line in the middle of my blender screen?

Tags: animation, mesh, armature

I am curious as to what the line in the middle of the screen could be.

When I move the dot on the bottom of this dashed line it moves my mesh, this line moves along with it.

Also in the middle of the screen there's another dot. It move my armature.

I'm trying to do an animation with this mesh but I can't figure what the correct way to do it with an animation and a mesh would be?

Here's an image: [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(from the [manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/pivot_point/individual_origins.html?highlight=origin))

> "The Origin of an Object is shown in the 3D view by a **small orange circle**.
>
> While the Origin is equivalent to the center of the Object, it does not have to be located in the center of the Mesh. This means that an Object can have its center located on one end of the mesh or even completely outside the mesh."

That **dotted line** means that an object is parented to other object.

> "Moving, rotating or scaling the parent will also usually move/rotate/scale the child/children. However moving/rotating/scaling the child/children of the parent will not result in the parent moving/rotating/scaling. In other words, the direction of influence is from parent to child and not child to parent."

Read this: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/groups_and_parenting.html

Answer (score 2):

The dots represent the center points of objects.  The one that moves your mesh is the center point of the mesh and the one that moves the armature is the center point of the armature.  The dotted line on the mesh center point shows that it is parented to something (in this case the armature).

You probably moved the mesh and armature in edit or pose mode and that is why the center points are not actually in the center of the objects.